# AltBeacon Ranging in the background (when not killed)

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

I'm trying to move my perfectly valid iOS scenario over to Android via AltBeacon:

The mobile app monitors for beacons. When mobile is in beacon range, didDetermineState is launched, in iOS it is done automatically when entering/leaving zones so I guess (hope) AltBeacon follows this. didDetermineState checks if we just went inside the region and if so, it launches ranging, if not - it stops ranging. The ranging decides what to do next based on distance. It works both in Foreground (then displays proper information) or in the background (then it displays notifications).

For me it is obvious and almost perfect scenario. However most examples treat Monitoring/Ranging like it is something competing (or at least totally separate), not cooperating.

I didn't want to make notifications when the app is killed (if possible), only when in Foreground or in the Background (when you go to the "desktop" or any other app without killing our app).

I tried to follow this scenario on Android and things doesn't look like I was hoping:

1. At launch the didDetermineState is launched automatically at start and it usually returns OUTSIDE.
2. The AltBeacon documentation clearly states, that BeaconConsumer should extend Activity or Service - does it mean that I can't range in Application class?
3. Is it even possible to Monitor and Range when App is in Background but not killed?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can combine ranging and monitoring in the application class.  Yes, you can start ranging in didDetermineState().  Just use the  **Starting an App in the Background** example on this page:

https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

And start ranging in the `didDetermineState()` callback.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I think I didn't write my questions clear (long day). I did check both the sample code and reference example from github. I did manage to range perfectly fine when enabled "by pressing button". I didn't manage to make monitoring in the background to work from github reference example (maybe because some parts are already obsolete or maybe the problem is somewhere else).

Comment: First problem is that didDetermineState returns OUTSIDE - I made condition there, INSIDE --> start ranging, OUTSIDE --> stop ranging, so things wont work here. As for ranging in the background - I meant background when app is not killed.

Comment: There is not really a point to ranging in an outside condition -- ranging callbacks would return 0 beacons.  Once a second didDetermineState callback is made with inside set, useful ranging will start automatically if you have the code you describe in place.  If that isn't working, something in the setup is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In the end I used just foreground ranging and monitoring (it works perfectly, when app is hidden, the ranging still works like it should). Somehow I failed to make it work in Application, even the https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference code (I just compiled without any changes) doesn't work. I will probably contact you regarding mobile antenna measurements as those are way out of scope on Samsung A5 (0.01m instead of 1m distance), but that is off topic.